# Issue getting box to float left or display inline

Tags: html, css, position

I am running into issues getting the boxes in my code to `float: left;` of each other or `display: inline-block;` I have moved them around into different divs that I have listed and I cannot get this to work. I created a fiddle to show what my code looks like right now:

https://jsfiddle.net/p4c8yrcz/

The containers I have moved and tried a lot of different options in are these..

```
.countdown_position {


/*display: inline-block;*/
    /*padding-left: 7%;*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
}
.countdownBox {
    border: 2px solid #B8B8B8;
    /*float: left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have fixed your countdown_position to 15% which stop the countdownBox to float left. Adjust the width to see the difference

Comment: I adjusted it to 10% and 100px. It still doesn't float left.

Comment: Try 100% and not smaller than 15%

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p4c8yrcz/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked on your code, you've got a `countdown_position` `width` set to 15%, which is causing the issue, check this out;

[Inline-block](https://jsfiddle.net/p4c8yrcz/10/)

**Update:**

For adding `float:left`to `countdown_out` div, remove `margin-left:15%`, and simply add `float:left`. The link is updated.

Comment: What can I add with to, so that this still works? I tried the `.countdownBox `, but if I do 2 of the boxes go to the next page.

Comment: you mean the next line ?

Comment: Yea, sorry. I just want to make the boxes large enough where all four will take up the container they are in.

Comment: well, if you like your boxes the fit the container, replace 70% to 100% on your "countdown-out" div....

Comment: I figured it out, I had to set `.countdown_position` to `width: 100%;` Thanks!